# Entity Framework: Belongs to Many?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have 3 Models: **Shop, Employee, WorkOrder**

**Shop**s have many **Employee**s, and many **Work Order**s. Everything works great until I want to make the **WorkOrder** belong to a **Shop** and, while making a single **Employee** accountable for completing it.

```
namespace TicketSystem.Models
{
    public class WorkOrder
    {
        public virtual int WorkOrderId { get; set; }
        public virtual int ShopId { get; set; }
        public virtual string Description { get; set; }
        public virtual Shop Shop { get; set; }

        // this breaks it:
        public virtual int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I get the following error as a result:

```
An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.WorkOrders_dbo.Shops_ShopId' on table 'WorkOrders' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.
```

The real question here: does this occur because this is bad design? I want to be able to list work orders by Shop as well as by Employee.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! What you are saying is an employee has many work orders and a shop has many employees and many work orders. As you can see, EF is getting super confused.

I would normalize to a single parent / child relationship and go from there. If you drop the `ShopId` from `WorkOrder`, you can still find what work orders belong to what shops through the employee:

```
var workOrderId = 1;
var shop = context
     .Shops
     .Include("Employees")
     .Include("WorkOrders")
     .First(x => x.Employees.Any(e => e.WorkOrders.Any(w => w.WorkOrderId == workOrderId)));
```

There is no need to duplicate the employee in work order.

Comment: Thanks! That makes a lot more sense. How would that look when wanting to return all work orders and not just one with a certain Id?

Comment: For example, `var shops = db.Shops.Include("Employees").Include("WorkOrders").ToList();` doesn't throw an error, but WorkOrders is empty.

Comment: That might have been too eager. Try: `var shops = db.Shops.Include("Employees").ToList(); var emps = db.Employees.Include("WorkOrders").ToList();`. I guess EF doesn't load up grand-children but parent-child only.

Comment: That still doesn't make ordering WorkOrders very clear.

Comment: Are you just trying to get all the data? How about a `ForEach()`? `shops.ForEarch(s => s.Employees = emps.Where(x => x.ShopId == s.ShopId));`. You just need to use Linq to bring in whatever you may need.